# GridLayout ,android:layout_columnWeight,android:layout_rowWeight is only used in API 21 current mine is 16

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

So I'm using   a gridlayout in witch I have multiple image view  this is my complete view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/dashboard_action_bar" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="4"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:useDefaultMargins="true"

        >

        <org.appspot.driver.util.CustomIconDashboard
            android:id="@+id/ic_map"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            custom:imageSrc="@drawable/ic_map"
            custom:imageTitle="MAP" />

        <org.appspot.driver.util.CustomIconDashboard
            android:id="@+id/ic_jobs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            custom:imageSrc="@drawable/ic_mission"
            custom:imageTitle="JOBS"
            custom:strokeSrc="@drawable/mission_drawable"/>

        <org.appspot.driver.util.CustomIconDashboard
            android:id="@+id/ic_poi"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            custom:imageSrc="@drawable/ic_poi"
            custom:imageTitle="POI" />

        <org.appspot.driver.util.CustomIconDashboard
            android:id="@+id/ic_sos"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            custom:imageSrc="@drawable/ic_sos"
            custom:imageTitle="SOS" />

        <org.appspot.driver.util.CustomIconDashboard
            android:id="@+id/ic_msg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            custom:imageSrc="@drawable/ic_message"
            custom:imageTitle="MESSAGES"
            custom:strokeSrc="@drawable/message_drawable"/>

        <org.appspot.driver.util.CustomIconDashboard
            android:id="@+id/ic_frais"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_rowWeight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            custom:imageSrc="@drawable/ic_note"
            custom:imageTitle="NOTES DE FRAIS" />

        <org.appspot.driver.util.CustomIconDashboard
            android:id="@+id/ic_contacts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_rowWeight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            custom:imageSrc="@drawable/ic_contact"
            custom:imageTitle="CONTACTS" />

        <org.appspot.driver.util.CustomIconDashboard
            android:id="@+id/ic_myplaces"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_rowWeight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            custom:imageSrc="@drawable/ic_my_places"
            custom:imageTitle="MY PLACES" />
    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am getting android:layout_columnWeight,android:layout_rowWeight is only used in API 21 current  mine is 16 
so I added   the support library

```
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.4.0'
```

and still getting the same error so
I changed

```
android:layout_columnWeight
```

to :

```
app:layout_columnWeight
```

and still not getting the result wanted because in APIs less than 21 the device is not taking layout_columnWeight and layout_rowWeight in consideration does this mean that  I have to change the minsdk of the app ?because I really don't wan't and I don't really want to use a gridview.